# Função Javascript não respeita condições do loop

Tags: javascript, loop, while

Boa tarde, sou novo aqui e estou usando o **JavaScript Scratchpad** do *Mozila Firefox* para executar códigos *Javascript*. Ele realmente irá atender às minhas necessidades, porém a condição de parada do loop while não está funcionando *(for também não funcionou)*. Além disso, a variável `i` não está tendo seu valor incrementando, impedindo que qualquer valor além do primeiro do `array` seja usado. Agradeço a qualquer resposta, obrigado.

Segue o código:

```
window.setInterval(function () {
   var inputs = [ 10595, 10243, 11514, 11053, 10449, 10208, 11160, 10970, 10706, 11075, 10400, 10112, 10086, 10503, 11910, 12110, 11537, 9694, 12112, 10793, 11728, 9532, 10389, 12983, 9533, 12424, 10697, 11997, 12121, 11606, 10526, 9729, 10143, 11737, 10025, 10700, 11564, 12623, 9324, 11761, 10008, 11780, 10105, 12230, 12489, 12649, 9083, 11192, 10010, 10984, 12075, 12075, 11026, 12194, 12335, 10035];
    var i = 0;
    do {
        Accountmanager.farm.sendUnits(this, inputs[i], 4202);
        i++;
    }
    while (i < 5)
}, 250);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se percebi bem queres ir passando os valores dessa array um a um com um intervalo de `250 ms`entre eles.

Podes fazer isso assim:

```
function processar(dados, delay) {

    var arr = dados.slice();
    function enviar() {
        var proximo = arr.shift();
        Accountmanager.farm.sendUnits(this, proximo, 4202);
        if (arr.length) setTimeout(enviar, delay);
    }
    setTimeout(enviar, delay);
}
```

A ideia é criar uma função que processa esse envio.
A cada linha `var arr = dados.slice();` cria uma cópia da array para não se perder o original.

Esta solução usa o setTimeout em vez do `setInterval` que nunca acaba até ser chamado um `clearInterval`.

Para iniciar o envio podes fazer `processar(inputs, 250);` onde escolhes o que envias e escolhes a velocidade também.

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/xp1pk0y0/

Comment: Inclusive o uso do da função slice() me ajudou alguns dias depois, pois precisei manter o array original para 'recarregar' o array utilizado na função(após todos os valores serem utilizados, se faz necessário reiniciar o array com os mesmos elementos).

Answer (score 4):

O loop está sendo executado corretamente mas você externamente está usando a função **setInterval**  que executa novamente a função a cada 250 milissegundos, se o que você quer é enviar todos os itens do seu array, você pode passar o tamanho dele na condição do while.

```
// código do seu array omitido

var i = 0;
do {
    Accountmanager.farm.sendUnits(this, inputs[i], 4202);
    i++;
} while (i < inputs.length)
```

Exemplo com o valor de cada item:
https://jsfiddle.net/hsxanz23/

Comment: Entendo, o problema era o interval, mas eu ainda quero que antes de cada ciclo do while, haja um delay, como proceder?

Comment: A cada x segundos você quer que ele envie os dados pra essa sua Accountmanager?

Comment: Preciso que a cada x segundos ele envia o comando accoun... com o valor de i incrementado. Inclusive testei seu codigo e ele só foi executado 1x o loop :(

Comment: O que você estava fazendo é que a cada 250ms ele mandava TODOS, não um. @MadsonPaulo

Comment: O codigo q eu estava utilizando, que postei la encima, enviada a cada 250ms o comando com o valor do array na posição i=0.

Comment: Não, ele tentava mandar todos os valores de `i` a cada 250ms.

Comment: @MadsonPaulo o interval não é uma `Thread.sleep` não, tu chama todos de forma assincrona

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal recebi muitos comentários em muito pouco tempo, não esperava todo esse suporte, muito obrigado, meu problema foi resolvido. O código final que estou usando é:

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    Accountmanager.farm.sendUnits(this, inputs.shift(), 4202);
}, 250);
```

Provavelmente foi esse shift() que faz todo o array ser percorrido, eu não conhecia :)

**Podem fechar o tópico, obrigado.**

Comment: O `shift` tira um elemento to início do array. Depois de um certo número de rodadas, a array estará vazia (aliás, acho que você precisaria verificar isso e cancelar o interval depois disso).

Comment: Juntei uma resposta. O `.shift()` vai buscar o primeiro elemento da array mas ao mesmo tempo modificando-a, removendo esse elemento.